# NodeJS Promise Never Returns (Mongoose / MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've been struggling with a promise function for a few hours now trying to figure out why it won't resolve.  I was led to looking into issues with Mongoose at some point but it seems to be doing the right thing elsewhere so I'm doubting that bit now.

The part where the below function seems to get stuck is at `user.save()`. It acquires the hashed password, creates the model (confirmed with logging), then attempts to return the `user.save()` promise (this is a mongoose model, which has a `save()` function that returns a promise), but I'm not sure anything happens after that.  I've placed logging in both the then / catch after the `return user.save()` promise and neither of them get called. `createUser` returns a promise that never resolves.

I was hoping I could have an extra set of eyes on the below to see where maybe I'm not properly writing this promise chain, otherwise I digress to my original theory that it's a Mongoose issue.

```
module.exports = {
  createUser: function () {
    const password = Faker.internet.password()
    return Passwords
      .hash(password)
      .then((hashedPassword) => {
        const user = new UserModel({
          firstName: Faker.name.firstName(),
          lastName: Faker.name.lastName(),
          username: Faker.internet.userName(),
          email: Faker.internet.email(),
          displayName: 'bs',
          passwordHash: hashedPassword
        })
        return user.save()
      })
      .then(doc => ([doc, password]))
  }
}
```

And the passwords class:

```
class Passwords {
  hash (password) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      try {
        resolve(bcrypt.hashSync(password, BCRYPT_SALT_ROUNDS))
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        reject(err)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a Promise anti-pattern.  There is no need to wrap one promise inside another.  Just return the first one you had and get rid of the `new Promise()` entirely.   `return Passwords.hash(...).then(...)`.  Then make sure the caller of `createUser()` has both a `.then()` and a `.catch()` on the returned promise.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `Passwords.hash()` returns a full-blown promise?

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks, but unfortunately I've just tried this and it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Then, replace `return user.save()` with `return user.save().then(val => {console.log("save finished"); return val;}).catch(err => {console.log("save error", err); throw err});` to log what happens to the `user.save()` promise.  This is just basic debugging to find out where things are stuck.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've just updated the question with your suggestion and added the password class

Comment: Isn't `.hash()` a method of an instance of a Passwords object, not a class method?  Where do you create an instance of that class?

Comment: @jfriend00 `const Passwords = require('../utilities/passwords')` is sitting at the top of the file. two separate files

Comment: I'm trying your suggestion now

Comment: And what is `Passwords` as used in `createUser()`?  Is it the class?  Because if it is, the class doesn't have a `.hash()` method.  You need to do `passwordObj = new Passwords()` so you can then do `passwordObj.hash()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 it's an instantiation of the Passwords class

Comment: Well, that's not very obvious from the code you show.  Too hard to debug all this stuff we can't see.

Comment: I understand, I would put my whole codebase up there but noone would want to read it :P

Comment: @jfriend00 i just figured it out, but I don't understand why my initially posted code doesn't work, mind taking a look? thanks for the help. hoping for an explanation of what i did wrong

Comment: @jfriend00 actually scratch that, removed it.  Neither the `then` or `catch` resolve from `user.save()`

Comment: I don't think i'm going crazy, thinking this is a mongoose thing again.

Comment: Your new code you briefly showed does NOT wait for `user.save()` to finish.  It ignores whether it finishes or not and lets everything else keep going.  The problem is apparently in `user.save()` if it's not resolving or rejecting.